# Map component: Cannot read property 'initialize' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-leaflet

I'm trying to get a basic map working using [react-leaflet.js](https://react-leaflet.js.org). Here's my code:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Map } from 'leaflet';

const mapStyle = {
  height: '400px'
};

const mapCenter = [0, -0];
const zoomLevel = 3;

export default class MapT extends React.PureComponent {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Map
          style={mapStyle}
          center={mapCenter}
          zoom={zoomLevel}
        >
        </Map>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

But I'm getting an error:

```js
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'initialize' of undefined
    at NewClass (leaflet-src.js:300)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:14003)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:14470)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:17014)
    at workLoop (react-dom.development.js:17054)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:149)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:199)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:256)
    at replayUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:16366)
    at renderRoot (react-dom.development.js:17148)
    at performWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:17993)
    at performWork (react-dom.development.js:17901)
    at performSyncWork (react-dom.development.js:17873)
    at requestWork (react-dom.development.js:17761)
    at scheduleWork (react-dom.development.js:17566)
    at Object.enqueueSetState (react-dom.development.js:11695)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need to import the React leaflet components from `react-leaflet` instead of `leaflet`.

```js
import { Map } from 'react-leaflet';
```

Comment: Never thought it would be a problem if I just auto import in VS Code, saved my day!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to be so late.
In above example there is not value for width.
If someone have the same issue, make sure to have: height and width setted on map component. For example:

If it doesn't works, change value for "position" in style